# Why does this Travis deploy to Heroku fail?

Tags: ruby, heroku, github, rake, travis-ci

I use Travis CI to build a Ruby app. The app is deployed to Heroku after a successful build. After upgrading from Cedar to Cedar-14 and changing Ruby version to 2.1.4 (as this was required for the stack upgrade) the deploy step fails when Heroku precompiles the project. I have tried various deploy strategies but without success. The logs don’t specify the invalid url which makes it hard to track the troubleshoot this issue. From the deploy log:

Running: rake assets:precompile
rake aborted!

ArgumentError: invalid url

/tmp/build_4345603424563456/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.0.7/lib/redis/client.rb:364:in `_parse_options’

When I push the app straight to Github, the deploy is successful and the stack upgrades to Cedar-14.

So, why does the Heroku deploy step suddenly fail when using Travis CI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was solved by passing the url to the Redis initialization constructor explicitly instead of using the 'old' way of passing the parsed symbols. The old way seems to work best (if not exclusively) with versions before Rails 4. This was confirmed by the Redis To Go documentation on Heroku: [Redis To Go](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/redistogo)

Rails 4

```
REDIS = Redis.new(:url => redis_url_string)
```

pre-Rails 4

```
uri = URI.parse(redis_url)
REDIS = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password)
```

For another, similar issue, see this post: [Why does Travis fail to connect use Redis cache_store when deploying to Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28067644/why-does-travis-fail-to-connect-use-redis-cache-store-when-deploying-to-heroku)