# Why does Travis fail to connect use Redis cache_store when deploying to Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment, redis, travis-ci

I use Redis caching in my Rails app:

```
config.cache_store = :redis_store, redis_url
```

When I push my Rails app straight to Heroku, it is deployed successfully. When using Travis, the Heroku deploy step fails because the asset precompilation attempts to connect to Redis.

```
   Running: rake assets:precompile
   rake aborted!
   ArgumentError: invalid uri scheme ''
   /tmp/build_7c5f167bf750cb2986dbb9c3510ea11e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.2.0/lib/redis/client.rb:390:in `_parse_options'
```

I have tried various things: overriding RedisStore methods using rake tasks, moving the cache_store instantiation to the initialization phase, using Docker instead of sudo, changing Heroku build strategy and other travis.yml configurations etc.

I don't want to precompile locally, and I'd rather not change caching solution. Many other apps running on the cedar-14 stack use a very similar setup so the issue seems a bit peculiar.

Any suggestions how to resolve this Travis+Heroku deploy issue?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, and for what its worth, I also see the issue when I fork my heroku app.

Comment: @joshrl Please see my answer below, in case you haven't solved it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved the problem by overriding the Redis::Store initialization. When using Travis to trigger the Heroku deploy, Redis Store tries to connect to Redis. This is probably due to the current version (Nov 2013) of the Redis Store gem not being compatible with the current asset pipeline implementation. The reason why this works when pushing straight to Heroku is unclear. It could be related to the order that assets are compiled, when using the Heroku build strategies as specified in the travis.yml file. Perhaps these issues will be resolved in future Redis Store versions.

This is the rake task used to avoid loading Redis when using Redis Store as cache store (lib/assets/tasks/assets.rake):

```
pt = Rake::Task['assets:environment']
Rake.application.send(:eval, "@tasks.delete('assets:environment')")

namespace :assets do
  task :environment do
    class Redis
      class Store
        def initialize(options = { })
          puts ”Do nothing"
        end
      end

      def initialize(options = { })
        puts ”Do nothing"
      end
    end
    pt.execute
  end
end
```

This is not a very elegant solution, but it does the trick for now. Consider changing the caching solution instead.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I solved this by changing the redis init to:

```
REDIS = Redis.new(:url => redis_url_string)
```

where previously I was parsing the URI and passing in the arguments as:

```
uri = URI.parse(redis_url)
REDIS = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password, :scheme => uri.scheme)
```

I wonder if the cache store init has a similar init implementation for redis (I haven't checked the source there).

Comment: I also had to replace the Redis.new parameters with ':url'. They changed the implementation at some point. This is however not related to this cache_store issue. However, we have solved the problem so I will answer my question some time today.